# Duda con envios de email HTML con SSMTP desde linux

Tags: php, linux

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$to = 'aquiroz@info-mat.com, lexquirox@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Website Change Reqest';


$message = '<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Test HTML</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; background: #f8f8f8; ">
<div width="100%" style="background: #f8f8f8; padding: 0px 0px; font-family:arial; line-height:28px; height:100%;  width: 100%; color: #514d6a;">
  <div style="max-width: 700px; padding:50px 0;  margin: 0px auto; font-size: 14px">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 20px">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-bottom:30px;" align="center"><a href="http://eliteadmin.themedesigner.in" target="_blank"><br/>
            </a> </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div style="padding: 40px; background: #fff;">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Dear Sir/Madam/Customer</b>
              <p>This is to inform you that, Your account with Elite Admin has been created successfully. Log it for more details.</p>
              <a href="javascript: void(0);" style="display: inline-block; padding: 11px 30px; margin: 20px 0px 30px; font-size: 15px; color: #fff; background: #00c0c8; border-radius: 60px; text-decoration:none;"> Call to action button </a>
              <p>This email template can be used for Create Account, Change Password, Login Information and other informational things.</p>
              <b>- Thanks (Test)</b> </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; color: #b2b2b5; margin-top: 20px">
      <p> Ok sender<br>
        <a href="javascript: void(0);" style="color: #b2b2b5; text-decoration: underline;">Unsubscribe</a> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: AQ <aquiroz@info-mat.com>, SQ <aquiroz@info-mat.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: Example Email <alexanderquiroz@info-mat.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: lexquirox@gmail.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: lexquirox@gmail.com';


if(mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers))){
  echo 'Mail Sent';

}else{


  echo 'Mail NOT Sent';



exit();

}
```

con este codigo intento enviar un correo HTML pero no logro realizar que me envie correctamente , ahora bien si cambio a texto plano:

```
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1';
```

Logro enviar el correo solamente con este formato

Uso SSMTP en Linux

Alguna sugerencia de que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿No considera el cuerpo del mensaje como HTML? ¿No considera bien los carácteres?

Comment: Hola @Davlio realmente no lo se , entiendo que lo estoy haciendo como corresponde y es alli mi duda

Comment: Quizás puedes usar `print_r(error_get_last());`, en el caso no envía y obtener el último error.

Comment: Gracias @Davlio voy a  intentar tu sugerencia

Comment: hola @Davlio este fue el error que me posteo : Mail NOT SentArray ( [type] => 32 [message] => PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20131226/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20131226/php_pdo_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [file] => Unknown [line] => 0 ) estoy ubicando si existe este archivo pero no existe

Comment: Para descartar, ¿Has realizado una prueba con un HTML simple?

Comment: Hermano @Davlio Agradezco tu tiempo es eso exactamente! use un esquema simple de html y logro enviarme el correo , en mi ejemplo modifique la seccion donde esta la tabla y me lo envio correctamente ahora ver que puedo hacer con ese diseno a lo mejor debo usar Divs en vez de tablas , pero agradezco tu tiempo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a @Davlio por su guia , pude darme cuenta que el problema reside en las imagenes y su path debo de realizar el path, el cual debe ser con una url, luego de remover estas imagenes para realizar un test en el html completo en su version original pude realizar el envio sin problemas.